# Retrieving contact info in Android fails with exception

Tags: android, sqlite

ALL,
I am trying to execute following piece of code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query( ContactContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '" + name + "'", null, null );
```

However when running this code, I am getting SQLite exception: "Don't know such file ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME:, while compiling "....."".

The problem is that I don't know in advance what will "name" contain, hence using "LIKE" clause.

Is there a better way to perform such operation? Or I am just doing it incorrectly?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Or I am just doing it incorrectly?

`ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` is a Java construct. Use:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query( ContactContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + name + "'", null, null );
```

Or, use positional parameters:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query( ContactContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", args, null );
```

where `args` is a one-element string array containing your `name`.